# C# WPF refresh ListView with lot of items hangs

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, refresh, lag

I have some kind of file explorer using a ListView to show the files. When i open a folder containing a few thousands of files, the UI hangs around 5 seconds while the ListView is refreshing.

Is there any way to avoid that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Virtualisation is a must for large collections like these. Without it, WPF will have to create a visual tree for EACH item in your list ahead of time.

Just a hunch, but are you using an ObservableCollection to bind the collection of files to the ListBox?

I've had performance problems with large collections and the ObservableCollection. You can only add/remove items on the UI thread - if you're iterating through your file results, and adding them to the observable collection then you're going to experience this kind of lag.

Best solution in that case is to compile your file list as a separate list, and create a new ObservableCollection, passing the list in through the constructor. This minimizes the hit on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Add the items to your ListView's datasource with DispatcherPriority set to Background.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new Action(() => AddNewITemToList(newItem));
```

Answer (score -1):

The performance problem you have now is related to a fact that control creates UI elements for all thousand of files found, even if renders only small amount of them.

You need *at least* use [ListView.VirtualMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to implement kind of paging in your control.

In practise what happens is that in this mode, the control's `ListViewItem` is created dynamicaly , so you can use `ItemsCollection` of it, but you can *control* the creation of every single item required by UI in single moment, so improve performance too.

There is also an option of [Data Virtualization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization), where the data bound to your control is virtualized too, and not only `UI` of the control.